# Does Kubernetes always give a shell to the running container

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I having my Pod manifest as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-nginx-container
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-alpine-container-1
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - containerPort: 80
```

And I can get a shell to the Container running my Nginx using `kubectl exec --stdin --tty pod-nginx-container -- /bin/sh`

My question is does Kubernetes always give a shell to the running container? I mean suppose I have created my own image of Tomcat webserver, and when I use that image then will I still get the shell to login to the container running Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Kubernetes

Kubernetes schedules [Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) to nodes. A Pod consists of one or more containers - that are instantiated from container images.

### Container image

A container image contains a command that will run as the main process but it can also contain other binaries and also a full Linux "userland" like e.g. Ubuntu with shell and lots of tools.

Container images *can* be built from "scratch" without any other software than e.g. your app, but typically contain some more software for your app to be runnable e.g. `glibc`. See [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) for minimal base images that does not contain a *shell*.

### Conclusion

> My question is does Kubernetes always give a shell to the running container? I mean suppose I have created my own image of Tomcat webserver, and when I use that image then will I still get the shell to login to the container running Tomcat?

Your container contain a shell, only if you have built in a shell - most likely by using a base image that contain a shell e.g. alpine or ubuntu.

It depends on what do you do in your `Dockerfile` before building a container image with `docker build`

Comment: Ok, I am using Minikube to learn Kubernetes and have very less knowledge about Docker so wasn't sure about it, thanks a lot for your helpful answer.

Comment: One more question if you know the answer - in k8s, I know Node is the VM and Container is process inside that VM, I know Pod is collection of Containers, so Pod is only a logical concept and nothing actual commuting resource like VM or process?

Comment: yes, that is correct. A pod is only an abstract grouping of containers, used in Kubernetes.